# Pedantic gcc warning: type qualifiers on function return type

Tags: c++, constants, gcc-warning

When I compiled my C++ code with GCC 4.3 for the first time, (after having compiled it successfully with no warnings on 4.1, 4.0, 3.4 with the `-Wall -Wextra` options) I suddenly got a bunch of errors of the form `warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type`.

Consider `temp.cpp`:

```
class Something
{
public:
    const int getConstThing() const {
        return _cMyInt;
    }
    const int getNonconstThing() const {
        return _myInt;
    }

    const int& getConstReference() const {
        return _myInt;
    }
    int& getNonconstReference() {
        return _myInt;
    }

    void setInt(const int newValue) {
        _myInt = newValue;
    }

    Something() : _cMyInt( 3 ) {
        _myInt = 2;
    }
private:
    const int _cMyInt;
    int _myInt;
};
```

Running `g++ temp.cpp -Wextra -c -o blah.o`:

```
temp.cpp:4: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
temp.cpp:7: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
```

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong that violates the C++ standard? I suppose that when returning by value, the leading `const` is superfluous, but I'm having trouble understanding why it's necessary to generate a warning with it. Are there other places where I should leave off the const?

Comment: See this similar question and answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1607188/why-is-type-qualifier-on-return-type-is-meaningless

Comment: I've seen warning like these before, nevertheless, I spent several minutes trying to understand what was going on in my code. Probably a better error reporting would speed up things. Instead of `warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type` something like `warning: please don't add const qualifier when you are returning by value`.

Comment: @Avio Why shouldn't we add the `const` qualifier to the function returning a value? We do this because we don't want the value to be able to change afterwards.

Comment: @Franky const int foo(); <- const is useless. Does literally nothing. const int & foo(); <- const is meaningful.

Answer (score 118, accepted):

It doesn't violate the standard. That's why they're *warnings* and not *errors*.

And indeed you're right — the leading `const` is superfluous. The compiler warns you because you've added code that in other circumstances might mean something, but in this circumstance means nothing, and it wants to make sure you won't be disappointed later when your return values turn out to be modifiable after all.

Comment: That it warns and not errors does not mean anything. Other invalid code like `sizeof(void)` also does merely warn, but is clearly forbidden. The Standard does not know the difference between warnings and errors: Both are diagnostics.

Comment: @litb: What he said is still correct. Of course the fact that they're warnings doesn't *guarantee* that it won't violate the standard as you say, but the *reason* they're made warnings instead of errors is that the compiler implementers did not want to prohibit it. And the reason they didn't want to prohibit it is because it does not violate the standard.

Comment: Does it violate the standard at all?

Comment: I think my first sentence was rather clear on that, @Philipp. Look at the question Johannes mentioned in the question comment: [Why is a type qualifier on a return type meaningless?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1607188/why-is-type-qualifier-on-return-type-is-meaningless)

Answer (score 23):

I encountered this warning when compiling some code that uses Boost.ProgramOptions. I use `-Werror` so the warning was killing my build, but because the source of the warning was in the depths of Boost I couldn't get rid of it by modifying my code.

After much digging I found the compiler option that disables the warning:

```
-Wno-ignored-qualifiers
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I had the same problem, and ended up setting Boost's include path with `-isystem` instead of `-I`, which suppresses all warnings raised by Boost headers.

Comment: @Philipp's solution is the correct one. Using -Wno-ignored-qualifiers will affect your code and prevent your compiler from issuing warnings you've created, whereas Philipp's solution will not affect warnings produce by your own code.

Answer (score 8):

Returning a constant value only makes sense when you return a reference or a pointer(in this case pointer to constant and not a constant pointer) because the caller is able to modify the referenced (pointed to) value.

Another comment on the code not related to your question:
I think it's better to use a setter instead of

```
int& getNonconstReference() {
    return _myInt;
}
```

Which will should be:

```
void setMyInt(int n) {
  _myInt = n;
}
```

Moreover, it's useless to return a const reference to an int. It does make sense for a bigger object whose copy or move is more expensive.

Answer (score 2):

Having this

`struct Foo { Foo(int) {} operator bool() { return true; } };`

and that

`Foo some_calculation(int a, int b) { Foo result(a + b); /*...*/ return result; }`

the example

`if (some_calculation(3, 20) = 40) { /*...*/ }`

compiles without a warning. Of course, this is rare. But isn't const correctness about making it hard for people to do things wrong? And with the expectation that people try things, that are wrong, the return type should be declared const.
And: g++ warns about ignoring the classifier, but does not ignore it. I think, the warning is about users that take the copy and ignore the const classifiers on their copy. But that should not be a warning, because this is absolutely correct behavior. And it makes sense to do this.

Comment: G++ wouldn't warn here if you added a `const`. The `const` qualifier is only ignored for non-class type return values.

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't -pedantic only allow strict adherence to the ISO standard?  Depending on -std= of course...

Answer (score 1):

This warning is also useful to avoid confusion when declaring functions returning pointers to objects which should not be modified:

```cpp
// "warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type"
// as the pointer is copied. 
Foo* const bar();

// correct:
const Foo* bar();
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between `const` on a basic type result, where it's ignored, and `const` on a class type result, where it generally wreaks havoc.

```
namespace i {
    auto f() -> int const { return 42; }
    void g( int&& ) {}
}

namespace s {
    struct S {};
    auto f() -> S const { return {}; }
    auto g( S&&  ) {}
}

auto main() -> int
{
    { using namespace i; g( f() ); }    // OK
    { using namespace s; g( f() ); }    // !The `const` prevents this.
}
```

This is why the compiler warns in the first case: it's a special case, that may not do what one naïvely could expect.

For modern programming it would IMHO be nice also with a warning about `const` on class type result, since it prohibits move semantics; a rather severe cost for whatever little advantage one envisioned.

Answer (score -5):

[**Scott Meyers**](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321334876) pointed out that there's pretty good reason why someone would want to return `const` values. Here's an example:

```
int some_calculation(int a, int b) { int res = 0; /* ... */ return res; }

/* Test if the result of the calculation equals 40.*/
if (some_calculation(3,20) = 40)
{

}
```

Do you see what I did wrong? This code is absolutely correct and should compile. The problem is that the compiler didn't understand that you intended to**compare instead of assign** the value `40`.

With a `const` return value the above example won't compile. Well, at least if the compiler doesn't discard the `const` keyword.

Comment: No, it shouldn't compile. The result of `some_calculation` is an rvalue of type int. You can't assign to rvalues of non-class type.

Comment: And if the return value is of class type, the `const` is correct and doesn't generate a warning.

Comment: Have you actually tried to compile this example? GCC gives "error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment", clang++ gives "error: expression is not assignable"

Comment: He probably meant `==`