# Why is a type qualifier on a return type meaningless?

Tags: c++, c

Say I have this example:

```
char const * const
foo( ){
   /* which is initialized to const char * const */
   return str;
}
```

What is the right way to do it to avoid the compiler warning "type qualifier on return type is meaningless"?

Comment: Is it just me or this question lacks clarity?

Comment: @Jean-Lou: I agree that the question's body itself is somewhat vague, but the question's title acutally conveys its meaning.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The way you wrote it, it was saying "the returned pointer value is const". But non-class type rvalues are not modifiable (inherited from C), and thus the Standard says non-class type rvalues are never const-qualified (right-most const was ignored even tho specified by you) since the const would be kinda redundant. One doesn't write it - example:

```
  int f();
  int main() { f() = 0; } // error anyway!

  // const redundant. returned expression still has type "int", even though the 
  // function-type of g remains "int const()" (potential confusion!)
  int const g();
```

Notice that for the type of "g", the const *is* significant, but for rvalue expressions generated from type `int const` the const is ignored. So the following is an error:

```
  int const f();
  int f() { } // different return type but same parameters
```

There is no way known to me you could observe the "const" other than getting at the type of "g" itself (and passing `&f` to a template and deduce its type, for example). Finally notice that "char const" and "const char" signify the same type. I recommend you to settle with one notion and using that throughout the code.

Comment: I recommend using always trailing "const" (char const * const), as that is the only way you can use "const" *consistently*. However, I am badly outnumbered on this...

Comment: @DevSolar: Most gurus (Sutter for example) seems to agree with you and place qualifiers AFTER the type (class const&, class volatile).

Comment: @DevSolar, just to clarify: They do not agree with you about the last trailing const. They may agree with your first const that appears after the type name.

Comment: @ litb - I didn't get that comment. You mean "they" (the gurus?) disagree with me and, in `int foo() const`, place the const elsewhere? /me confused.

Comment: @Dev, i mean they do not agree that `int const f()` is good. They will omit that last trailing const (notice that this is not the same as `int f() const` - it's an entirely different thing). Matthieu (and me too) agrees with you in that `const` after the type is alright (like `int const a = 0;`). But not that it's good as trailing const in function return types (as your comment *may* indicate - so i wanted to clarify).

Comment: Ahh... now I get it. Indeed I didn't mean the trailing const of the function return type, but merely to always use *trailing* const **where const is appropriate** (which `int const f()` isn't).

Answer (score 6):

In C, because function return values, and qualifying values is meaningless.
It may be different in C++, check other answers.

```
const int i = (const int)42; /* meaningless, the 42 is never gonna change */
int const foo(void); /* meaningless, the value returned from foo is never gonna change */
```

Only objects can be meaningfully qualified.

```
const int *ip = (const int *)&errno; /* ok, `ip` points to an object qualified with `const` */
const char *foo(void); /* ok, `foo()` returns a pointer to a qualified object */
```

Comment: Note that for class types, the `const` for return values is not meaningless, as you are allowed to call modifying member functions on non-const rvalues. (We just had this here with strings the other day: `(s1+s2).append(s3)`.) As usual, litb's answer explains all this both in detail and correctness.

Comment: I meant my answer to deal with C only. Updated to reflect that.

Comment: Ah, he's asked a "C/C++" question. (Strange language, that.) Sorry, I hadn't seen this either.

Answer (score 2):

None of the previous answers actually answer the "right way to do it" part of the question.

I believe that the answer to this is:

```
char const * foo( ){
```

which says you are returning a pointer a constant character.

Comment: I understand this to be a constant pointer to a character, not a pointer to a constant char

Comment: No, actually @user1076543 is right, it's a pointer to a constant char as `char const *` and `const char *` are the same. A constant pointer to a character would be `char * const`.