# Why is the pointer not implicitly converted into <type> const*const

Tags: c++, pointers, constants, keil

`AT45Status` is a struct with several members and I have the following function:

```
/**
 * @brief read the chip status from the flash chip
 * @retval a pointer to the current status of the chip
 */
AT45Status const * const ReadChipStatus(void) {
  uint8_t commands[1] = {STATUS_READ};
  static AT45Status status;

  //// … details, but the result is updated values inside status

  return &status;
}
```

I get the following warning if I compile this using C++:

> …(16): warning:  #815-D: type qualifier on return type is meaningless

I of course looked up [an exact explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1607306/8548828) and it is a relevant warning for a trivial type which is value semantically passed. But I'm returning a pointer to an object which I don't want to be changed. (pointer or the data pointed to). As such the type qualifier is meaningful.

The warnings disappear when I change the return statement into:

```
return (AT45Status const * const)&status;
```

Why can't/doesn't the compiler implicitly cast an `AT45Status*` into an `AT45Status const * const`? What am I missing in this interaction?

Comment: All pointers are trivial types. They can not be changed even without const qualifiers. `ReadChipStatus() = nullptr;` is invalid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The warning is trying to tell you that you're trying to return a `const` pointer, which is meaningless, because the returned pointer itself can't be modified.

On the other hand, qualify the object being pointed as `const` is meaningful (to make the object pointed to unmodifiable), i.e. returning a pointer to `const`. e.g.

```
AT45Status const * ReadChipStatus(void)
```

Answer (score 1):

For example such a declaration like

```
const int f();
```

does not make sense for fundamental types. The returned value is a temporary object and cannot be changed even if you will remove the const qualifier.

```
int f();
```

For example you may not write

```
++f();
```

The compiler will issue an error.

The same situation takes place with the pointer.