# Disable specific warning in g++ using warning number

Tags: c++, g++, compiler-warnings

I would like to suppress the warning #858 in g++:

```
warning #858: type qualifier on return type is meaningless
```

and possibly others. I know I've done this before (although [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/487108/how-to-supress-specific-warnings-in-g) seems to say you can't), but don't remember how.

I've been trying to look for this warning in [this list](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html) to see if I could disable it using `-Wno...`, but none of them seem to fit.

Comment: Apparently `-Wno-ignored-qualifiers` does it (source: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1134237/pedantic-gcc-warning-type-qualifiers-on-function-return-type)

Comment: Since when do g++ warnings have numbers?

Comment: Oops I forgot that I was on a different machine where the makefile automatically uses an intel compiler! I'd delete the question but if I do would you still retain your upvotes?

Comment: There aren't any upvotes...

Comment: I mean on slugonamission and T.c.'s comments.